# Post to facebook in Laravel

Tags: laravel, facebook-share

I have this line of code that is supposed to post to facebook

```
$response = $fb->post('/me/feed', $data);
```

But i get this response saying

```
"Requires either publish_actions permission, or manage_pages and 
publish_pages as an admin with sufficient administrative permission"
```

Now this is how I get the url that will redirect me to the post-to-facebook route with all the necessary actions.

```
  $login_url=Facebook::getLoginUrl(['email','publish_actions','manage_pages','publish_pages'],route('post-to-facebook'));
```

But I still get the same error. Any help here will be appreciated.

Comment: I think it's connected with your settings on the facebook. Do you really have such kind or permissons? https://developers.facebook.com/apps/facebook_app_id/review-status/

Comment: @Pavel I do not have any such settings. In fact I created a new account, so there are all access permissions.

Comment: but in this case, you should check that facebook allowed to use it, because by default, Facebook gives you only these permissions: email, public_profile,user_friends.